# How to create an empty tgz file?

Tags: bash, macos, tar, bsd, gzip

How to create an empty tgz file?
I tried

```
tar czvf /tmp/empty.tgz --from-file /dev/null
tar: Option --from-file is not supported
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The switch you're looking for is `--files-from` or `-T`:

```
tar czvf /tmp/empty.tgz --files-from=/dev/null
```