# Empty a file in linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, file, echo

which one is the best way to clean or empty a file in Linux?
I have to zip ( tar ) a file to an archive and then clean/empty it; this is what I do and it works correctly:

```
tar -zcvf /mnt/file.tar.gz /mnt/file.txt > /dev/null 2>&1

echo "" > /mnt/file.txt
```

I'm doing it with echo, probably there is a better way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

There are multiple ways to do that:

We presume that our file is called access.log and it's in the current directory:

1.

```
: > access.log
```

2.

```
true > access.log
```

3.

```
cat /dev/null > access.log
```

4.

```
cp /dev/null access.log
```

5.

```
dd if=/dev/null of=access.log
```

6.

```
echo -n "" > access.log
```

7.

```
echo -n > access.log
```

Comment: 1. `> access.log`  is enough

Answer (score 8):

Just truncate it:

```
truncate -s 0 file
```

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT(zipping file and nullifying actual file):*** Taking inspiration from @oguz ismail's fine answer, I am using `truncate` option with zip of the file too here.

```
tar -zcvf file.tar.gz file.txt && truncate -s 0 file.txt
```

---

---

I will go with `> /mnt/file.txt` a bit easier than `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

one option is:

```
touch passbook.txt
```

Another option to make empty file in Linux is just type the following command:

```
> file-name-here
echo '' > filename
ls filename
file filename
```

Comment: `touch` will only update the file stamp of the file if it already exists. If the file does not exist, `touch` will create it, and it will be empty, but that was not the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
tar czvf /tmp/empty.tar.gz --files-from=/dev/null --overwrite
```

I found a way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44807644/how-to-create-an-empty-tgz-file)

Comment: IMHO I don't think OP is looking to create an empty zip file, he/she is looking for zipping a file and then nullifying actual file, if I got it correctly.